# hg pull patch cannot be decoded

Tags: version-control, mercurial

upon trying to pull from a repo I get the following error

```
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.6.1)
** Extensions loaded: eol, tortoisehg.util.hgcommands, tortoisehg.util.partialcommit, tortoisehg.util.pipeui, tortoisehg.util.win32ill, tortoisehg.util.hgdispatch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 49, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 54, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 116, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 187, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 920, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 679, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1051, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1011, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 917, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 801, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 5920, in serve
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyo", line 832, in service
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 290, in run
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 243, in serve
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 221, in serveone
  File "mercurial\commandserver.pyo", line 204, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 116, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 187, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 183, in closure
  File "tortoisehg\util\hgdispatch.pyo", line 23, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 920, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 679, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1051, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1011, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 917, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 801, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 5282, in pull
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 170, in peer
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 152, in _peerorrepo
  File "hgext\eol.pyo", line 354, in reposetup
  File "hgext\eol.pyo", line 299, in _hgcleardirstate
  File "hgext\eol.pyo", line 292, in loadeol
  File "hgext\eol.pyo", line 217, in parseeol
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 70, in __getitem__
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 563, in filectx
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 247, in filenode
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 239, in _fileinfo
  File "mercurial\manifest.pyo", line 965, in find
  File "mercurial\manifest.pyo", line 956, in read
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 1115, in revision
mpatch.mpatchError: patch cannot be decoded
cmdserver: process exited unexpectedly with code 255
```

Trying to search this I found advice to attempt to verify on the repo which tells me about corruption starting at revision 302

However when I try to (on the remote system holding the repository) do hg recover I simply get told there are no interrupted transactions.

I saw other things suggestion I needed to reinstall mercurial but
A) I attempted that and
B) other repositories seem to be fine

What issues could be causing this or alternatively what do I need to do to get more information to identify the problem?

edit to add: I also attempted re-cloning the project but get a similar error to trying to pull. I was able to pull and push to the repo fine from a separate machine.

I had a co-worker try to pull from the same repo and he got the following:

```
pulling from /Volumes/SourceRepo/Yoda/BSD_Transformation
searching for changes
adding changesets
python(41809,0x7fff7592e000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc872603058: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Corrupted" does not mean there's an interrupted transaction; hg would tell you so upon push or pull. It means something is broken with the repository state itself (starting with revision 302 in your case). Something tampered with files in the .hg directory and subsequently HG misses information about the repository history which it thinks it should have.

The exact output of `hg verify` would be the interesting thing to look at.

Try to clone  the healthy part of the repo using `hg clone -r301` and then try to recover as much from the broken repository as possible. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption gives more detailed advice based on what `hg verify` tells you being wrong.